# PHP Mail | No llegan los correos del formulario a mi servidor de correo

Tags: php, html, email

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que llegue el correo que envío desde un formulario a un correo de mi empresa.

He intentado con mi correo de gmail y funciona correctamente. Pero envío desde otro correo y no llegan...

Mi formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="php/enviarmails/enviarContactos.php" >
    <div class="fields">
        <div class="field half" >
            <label for="nombre" >Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" />
        </div>
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="email" >Correo Electronico</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="celular" >Celular</label>
            <input type="text" name="celular" id="celular" />
        </div>
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="empresa" style="color:#46A1BE">Empresa</label>
            <input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="mensaje" style="color:#46A1BE">Escriba un mensaje</label>
            <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="6" ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar Mensaje" class="primary" /></li>
        <li><input type="reset" value="Limpiar"  /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Mi código php:

```
<?php  
    $texto_mail=$_POST["mensaje"];
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $celular=$_POST["celular"];
    $empresa=$_POST["empresa"];
    $destinatario="contacto@cygnus.com.py";
    $asunto="Escribieron en contactos CYGNUS";
    $headers="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers.="From: Escribieron en la Pagina < contacto@cgynus.com.py >\r\n";
    $exito=mail($destinatario,$asunto,"Correo Electronico " . $email . "<br>" . "Nombre: " . $nombre . "<br>Celular: ". $celular . "<br> Empresa: " . $emrpesa .  "<br> Comentario del mensaje: " . $texto_mail ,$headers);

    if ($exito) {
        header("location: ../../enviadoContactos.html");
    } else {
        echo "Ha ocurrido un error";
    }
?>
```

La verdad que no sé bien si es mi hosting o el servidor de correo de la empresa la razon por la cual no llegan.

Si tienen algo de experiencia sobre esto se los agradecería.

Comment: Estás haciendo las pruebas en tu máquina con un servidor local? (con un XAMPP, por ejemplo?)

Comment: No, ya la subi a un hosting, solo llega con un correo de gmail, no se si es el servidor de correo de mi empresa que tiene restricciones o el hosting no deja enviar a ese correo

Comment: y si llegan a otro lado y no a tu empresa.. va a ser dificil ayudarte ya que es algo que no vamos a poder reproducir.

Comment: Cuando dices que funciona con gmail pero no con el correo de tu empresa, te estás refiriendo siempre al destinatario del e-mail, no?

Comment: Exacto, primero probe un destinatario con correo de gmail, y me funciono sin problemas, luego lo probe con el otro que esta ahi y de otro de la empresa y no me funcionaron...

Comment: Si no te funciono con un destinatario de tu empresa y estas usando o configurastes tu correo en php para que fuera con gmail, el problema esta con el servidor de tu empresa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh tenido este problema en el pasado con algunos dominios y se debe a que la función mal de PHP originalmente no cumple con el puntaje mínimo para no ser considerado spam, en algunos casos el mensaje ni siquiera es enviado a bandeja de spam sino que es desechado directamente.

Te recomiendo usar **PHPMailer** (Disponible en https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Es la mejor opción, solo crea una cuenta de correo en tu hosting (por ejemplo notificaiones@tudominio.com) esta te servirá para configurar tu PHPMailer y al tratarse de un correo enviado por un protocolo y correo existente de seguro que si llegara a todos los destinatarios (o Por lo menos a Spam).

Uso básico.

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->isSMTP();      
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //ACTIVALO SI QUIERES VER EL DEBIG
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$mail->Host = $config_notificaciones_defecto_host;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $config_notificaciones_defecto_username;                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $config_notificaciones_defecto_pasword;                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = $config_notificaciones_defecto_smtpsecure;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = $config_notificaciones_defecto_puerto;    
$mail->setFrom($config_notificaciones_defecto_fromcorreo, $config_notificaciones_defecto_frondescripcion);
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // NO CERRAR LA CONEXION HASTA ENVIAR TODOS LOS CORREOS

$mail->Subject = "Bienvenido a MI WEB "; 
$mail->AltBody = 'SOY UN RESUMEN PARA CELULAR';

$mail->Body    ='<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body style="background: #e4e9f0;">
   SOY UN CORREO
</body>
</html>';

$paquien=$mail_bienvenido_destino;

    $mail->addAddress($paquien, $paquien);
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $paquien) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        break; //Abandon sending
    }

    // LIMPIARMOS DIRECCION Y ADJUNTOS PARA CONTINUAR
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();

?>
```